# Makefile don't find rule

Tags: makefile, build, jekyll, gnu-make

I'm in a [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) project with the following `makefile`:

```
project = jekyll-template-repository

e:          execute
execute:
            bundle
            build


r:          run
run:
            jekyll serve -l -o -b /$(project)


b:          build
build:      clean
            jekyll build

c:          clean
clean:
            jekyll clean
```

And when I run `make execute`, it throw me the error `make: build: Command not found`

I suppose it is trying to execute it as a common bash command, however I would like to call the `build` rule I wrote forward in the file. Is there some special syntax required to point  to other `make` rules when they aren't right after another rule `:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "call" rules in a makefile.  Rules aren't functions.  You can *depend* on a *target*, in which case that target will be made up to date before this target can be considered up to date.

Each recipe of a rule is, indeed, a shell script.  It's not ever a list of other targets.

You can write:

```
execute: build
```

then it will first execute the `build` target's recipe (assuming it's not up to date), then after that it will execute the recipe for the `execute` target.

Comment: Perfect, I got it. I'm stabilizing target precedence, consequently I couldn't _call_ them from the middle of another target execution! Thanks